# Get a list of folders that contain vb files using powershell

Tags: powershell

```
 Get-ChildItem  -Recurse -Filter *.vb
```

Will return all vb files in my solution. However I don't want all the files, what I want is a list of all the folders that contain vb files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "Your base path here" -filter *.vb -recurse -File | Select -unique DirectoryName
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

here's one way to do it. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- sets the constants
- gets the files that match the target type
- gets the `.Directory` property of each file
- sorts for just the unique items
- gets the `.FullName` property of those dirs
- saves them to a collection
- shows that collection on screen

the code ...

```
$SouceDir = $env:TEMP
$Filter = '*.log'

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SouceDir -Filter $Filter -File -Recurse

$DirsWithTargetFileType = ($FileList.Directory |
    Sort-Object -Unique).FullName

$DirsWithTargetFileType
```

output ...

```
C:\Temp
C:\Temp\zzz
C:\Temp\zzz - Copy
C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\test 4.poiu
C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\TestingStuff - Copy\CDelta\Documents
C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\TestingStuff\CDelta\Documents
C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Users - Copy\CDelta\Documents
C:\Temp\zzz - Copy\Users\CDelta\Documents
C:\Temp\zzz\TestingStuff - Copy\CDelta\Documents
C:\Temp\zzz\TestingStuff\CDelta\Documents
C:\Temp\zzz\Users - Copy\CDelta\Documents
C:\Temp\zzz\Users\CDelta\Documents
```

the above is just the dir names as strings. if you need the full objects, remove the `.FullName` at the end of line 7.